# Elasticsearch fast query but slow response time when retrieving _source even if nested fields are in _source_exclude

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping

```
{
  "yellows" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "yellow" : {
        "properties" : {
          "ranges" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "geometry" : {
                "type" : "geo_shape"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "other1" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
              },
              "other2" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "other3" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          }
          ...
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

queries gets slower and slower the bigger the `size`. For example

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source_exclude=ranges&from=0&size=50' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
# size 50 -> "took":71

curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source_exclude=ranges&from=0&size=100' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
# size 100 -> "took":1421
```

At the same time, queries of `size=0` or with `_source=false` are fast. For example

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source_exclude=ranges&from=0&size=0' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
# size 0 -> "took":32

curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source=false&from=0&size=100' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
# _source=false -> "took":167
```

That means that queries retrieving the `_source`s (ie without `_souce=false` or `size=0`) are slower. Also, it seems that the more ranges in the retrieved documents the slower is the response. I’m using `wc -c` in the following as a proxy measure of how many ranges are in the retrieved documents. Not the best measure but should suffice

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?from=0&size=50' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}' | wc -c
# 2.332.822

curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?from=50&size=50' --data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}' | wc -c
# 38.591.502
```

As you can see the first 50 have much less ranges than the second 50 in the first 100. Also, notice that in the first snippet, the query for the first 50 is much faster than the query for the second 50 even if it has `_source_exclude=ranges`.

It seems to me that the query is not the bottleneck. In fact, with `size=0` or with `_source=false` the response time is small. So I suspect that it’s the fact that ranges are a nested field and Elastic takes them into consideration even if the request excludes them (ie `_source_exclude=ranges`).

Is there any other way to make the queries faster without changing the mapping or should I change the mapping so that ranges are not nested?

Comment: That doesn't make sense because I thought ES stored nested fields as separate documents. So it shouldn't be that big a difference to remove the link. What does your configuration look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, query isn't the bottleneck. What you observe is the growing time of the [fetch phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html) of the request, while the search remains the same and rather small.

The search request is performed by Elasticsearch in roughly two phases: [Query phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_phase.html) and [Fetch phase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_fetch_phase.html).

In the Query phase ES determines which documents match the query, and to do so it uses fast indexes, that are most likely cached in RAM.

In the Fetch phase it actually fetches them from the disk and sends back the response. (The fetch is actually distributed, because matched documents can be located in any node of the cluster.)

Now let's see what happens in each of the cases you mentioned.

#### What happens when we have `size=0`?

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source_exclude=ranges&from=0&size=0' \
--data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
```

In this case you tell Elasticsearch to skip the fetch phase: it returns only the number of matched documents. It does not do any sorting either, because it is not needed.

#### What happens when we have `_source=false` and `size=100`?

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?_source=false&from=0&size=100' \
--data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}'
```

[`_source=false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-uri-request.html) tells Elasticsearch not to fetch JSON from disk. It only returns the document ids, in this case sorted by desired order. Sorting is also [performed mostly in memory](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-sort.html#_memory_considerations):

> When sorting, the relevant sorted field values are loaded into memory.
>   This means that per shard, there should be enough memory to contain
>   them.

That's why this query is also fast.

#### What happens with `from=50&size=50`?

```
curl https://path/to/elastic/yellows/_search?from=50&size=50' \
--data-binary '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[],"filter":{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"...":["1"]}},{"terms":{"...":["..."]}}],"should":[]}}}},"sort":[{"...":{"order":"asc"}}]}' | wc -c
```

Here we ask Elasticsearch to skip first 50 records and give next 50. As you have measured, the response is around 36MB, which is quite a lot. The first 50 records require transfer of only 2MB of data.

What happens is that Elasticsearch finally has to access the disk, and moreover, to send a lot of data - not just few 100KB - over the network. And this is why your query is slower. 1.5 seconds to transfer ~36MB gives us 24MB/sec (200 MBit/sec) transmission speed, which is a virtual limit of a fiber connection, for instance.

It is true that querying nested fields is slower than normal ones, but in this case it is not likely to be the problem: reading data from disk and sending it over network is.

#### How can I improve disk-related bottleneck?

Here are some hints on [Tuning for search speed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/tune-for-search-speed.html#_give_memory_to_the_filesystem_cache_2), in particular it is suggested to give more memory to file system cache.

#### How can I send less data over the network?

You have already discovered that you can exclude certain data from the response using `_source_exclude=ranges`. In case when you still need the response, but you only care for the subset of that `ranges` array, you can use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-inner-hits.html) to do so. By default it will return top-3 matching nested sub-documents.

#### Final considerations

It is always hard to give performance optimization advice since it heavily depends on the data structure, its amount and use cases. It is important to identify the bottleneck; in your case I would first check the disk read/write capabilities and the network.

To identify bottlenecks in the query itself I would recommend to take a look at [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-profile.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I left the team before we could solve the issue. But I believe @Nikolay is on spot with the analysis. The only thing to notice is that the bottleneck was not in the amount of data sent over the network in my case. That's clear by taking a look at the `took`s in my question. I was sending the data over the network while debugging "as a proxy measure of how many ranges are in the retrieved documents". Thank you so much for taking the time!

Comment: Some more info here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-fast-query-but-slow-response-time-when-retrieving-source-even-if-nested-fields-are-in-source-exclude/136280/2

Comment: @3v0k4 Glad I could help somehow!